# How can I cache rendered views for particular routes with Express/Node.js in temporary memory?

Tags: node.js, caching, express

I'm using Express/Node.js/Mongodb.

I have a website with around 200 pages that are static in the sense that they don't change until I manually update the database (which happens every couple of days). These 200 pages have up to 50-60 requests per second at times, so I believe I could benefit from caching the actual rendered result (as it is rather process intensive).

I'd like to cache the actual rendered page in temporary memory so that as soon as I restart my node.js server it clears the cache. I'm aware of how I might go about caching the results of the database requests, but I'm not sure how I might cache the actual rendered result of the page (as this would save quite alot of processing).

Does anyone know of any caching methods/middleware that would allow me to cache the rendered page in memory, so that I can clear it when I restart the server?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to implement some sort of browser caching, and not get the request at all

Comment: @adeneo That would be easier, but the nature of the website requires that as soon as I update the data/restart server I need all requests to show up to date data (as some pages are removed/added/links changed etc.)